# pass querystring value to open relevant jquery tab on naext page

Tags: jquery, tabs, querystringparameter

i have a link on page 1 with querystring `href="page2.html?selected=1"`.

What i want is when i click on this link on page 1 then it should navigate to page 2.html and use this querystring value to open particular jquery tab(using jquery tabs)??

Function is as follows:

```
$(function selectTab(indexId){
    var activeTab = location.href;
    var activeTabId = activeTab.substring(activeTab.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', indexId);
})
```

Please tell me how can i resolve this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, but your variables are mixed up, it would just be:

```
$(function selectTab(){
    var activeTab = location.href;
    var activeTabId = activeTab.substring(activeTab.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', activeTabId);
})
```

*However*, there's already built-in support for this, just use a URL like this:

```
page2.html?#tabPanelID
```

For example if the tab has a link of `href="#tab3"` that goes to a `<div id="tab3">` then your URL would be `page2.html#tab3`, check out this link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#tabs-3

See how it opens directly to the third tab in the demo? that's the built-in behavior.

Comment: I am trying use your sample for http://minth.amazyne.com/v-1.6/shortcode-tabs.html page. but it is not working

Comment: I just tried  http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#tabs-3 the third tab did not open.  First tab did. Same result on Chrome Version 58.0.3089, Safari 10.0.2 , Firefox 53.0.2, Opera 43.0.2442

Answer (score 1):

Try this way... I know it s  a bit long winded but at least you can see each stage of how JS Tabs is implemented.

Add a telltale to your string once the page reloads... I have done tab222.

Then ID your tab content div's i have done #tab_2

change the menu  tag href to what you have...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if (/tab222/.test(self.location.href)) {
    $('#p_tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $('#p_tabs li a[href="#tab_2"]').parent().addClass('active');
    $('#tab_one').removeClass('active');
    $('#tab_two').addClass('active');
  };

});
```

vwala! Hope that helps.